Function checking if a given char* already exists in a list always returns true
My program is supposed to load data from a CSV file, where the last part of every line is the label of the given data point. Since the labels will repeat themselves, it's more efficient to simply store a list of those labels, and the data created inside the program can store indexes to the correct labels. The list of labels is implemented as such (handling of temp == NULL will be added later):
typedef struct _LabelList {
    size_t size;
    char **label_table;
} LabelList;

void add_label(LabelList *list, char *label) {
    if (list->label_table == NULL) {
        list->size = 1;
        char **temp = malloc(sizeof(char *));
        if (temp != NULL) {
            list->label_table = temp;
            list->label_table[0] = label;
        }

        return;
    }
    else {
        list->size++;
        size_t temp_size = list->size;
        char **temp = realloc(list->label_table, temp_size * sizeof(char *));
        if (temp != NULL) {
            list->label_table = temp;
            list->label_table[temp_size-1] = label;
        }

        return;
    }
}

The seemingly problematic function looks like this:
int check_if_exists(LabelList list, char *to_check) {
    size_t length = list.size;
    int exists;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        exists = strcmp(list.label_table[i], to_check);
        if (exists == 0) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

If the given char* is already present in the list, the function returns its index in the list, otherwise it returns -1. Tested on its own, it works totally fine. The problem arises when it's invoked by another function.
LabeledDataPoint *create_labeled_data_point(char *data, size_t rec_count, LabelList *label_list) {
    char *token;
    char *end;
    LabeledDataPoint *point = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + rec_count*sizeof(double) + sizeof(char *));
    
    point->dims = rec_count-1;

    token = strtok(data, ",");
    point->data[0] = atof(token);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < rec_count-1; i++) {
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        point->data[i] = atof(token);
    };

    token = strtok(NULL, ",");

    int index_in_list = check_if_exists(label_list, token);

    if (index_in_list == -1) {
        add_label(label_list, token);
        point->label_num = label_list->size-1;
    }
    else {
        point->label_num = index_in_list;
    }

    return point;
}

LabeledDataPoint **load_labeled_data_csv(FILE *file, size_t num_records, size_t num_fields, LabelList *label_list) {
    LabeledDataPoint **all_data = malloc(num_records*(sizeof(size_t) + num_fields*sizeof(double)));

    LabeledDataPoint *current_data_point;
    char *current_record = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    int chars_num;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_records; i++) {
        chars_num = getline(&current_record, &n, file);
        if (chars_num != -1) {
            current_data_point = create_labeled_data_point(current_record, num_fields, label_list);
        }
        all_data[i] = current_data_point;
    }
    free(current_record);

    return all_data;
}

First label is added to label_list just as anticipated, however, each subsequent run of check_if_exists by create_labeled_data_point always returns 0.
I tried my best to pinpoint the bug. It turns out that when I print the first element of the label_list inside check_if_exists, it's always exactly the same as the to_check argument, and that's why strcmp returns 0 every time. Also, first time around I tried implementing that with a linked list, but the issue was the same.
EDIT:
Thanks to the comments I've solved this issue. Two functions had to be changed:
LabeledDataPoint *create_labeled_data_point(char *data, size_t rec_count, LabelList *label_list) {
    char *token;
    char *end;
    LabeledDataPoint *point = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + rec_count*sizeof(double) + sizeof(char *));
    
    point->dims = rec_count-1;

    token = strtok(data, ",");
    point->data[0] = atof(token);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < rec_count-1; i++) {
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        point->data[i] = atof(token);
    };

    token = strtok(NULL, ",");

// last token is copied, so the "data" pointer can be freed
    char *token_copy = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    strcpy(token_copy, token);

    int index_in_list = check_if_exists(*label_list, token);

// if a label is already in the list, the copied token is freed here
// otherwise that pointer will have to be freed after the list becomes obsolete
    if (index_in_list == -1) {
        add_label(label_list, token_copy);
        point->label_num = label_list->size-1;
    }
    else {
        point->label_num = index_in_list;
        free(token_copy);
    }

    return point;
}

LabeledDataPoint **load_labeled_data_csv(FILE *file, size_t num_records, size_t num_fields, LabelList *label_list) {
    LabeledDataPoint **all_data = malloc(num_records*(sizeof(size_t) + num_fields*sizeof(double)));

    LabeledDataPoint *current_data_point;
    char *current_record = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    int chars_num;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_records; i++) {
        chars_num = getline(&current_record, &n, file);
        if (chars_num != -1) {
            current_data_point = create_labeled_data_point(current_record, num_fields, label_list);
        }
        all_data[i] = current_data_point;
 // current_record is now freed and returned to NULL after each iteration
       free(current_record);
        current_record = NULL;
        n = 0;
    }

    return all_data;
}

And for easy freeing of the used memory:
void free_label_list(LabelList *list) {
    size_t size = list->size;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        free(list->label_table[i]);
    }

    free(list->label_table);
}


Might want to read up on what getline does when fed a non-null buffer pointer argument. Only your first call to getline has a null current_record going in; all the rest reuse the same buffer. Therefore, the most-recent row read will be the content shared by all unless an internal resize happens, in which case all prior rows suddenly have invalid pointers in your list).

In add_label(), for the realloc() case you set temp_size = list->size, and use that for the new size. Did you want the new size to be list->size + 1?

@WhozCraig thank you! You're right, I wanted to make use of the getline behaviour when it's fed a null buffer, but forgot to set it back to null after each use. I will rework the code with this in mind and post it in an edit.

@glacierDexeryl Don't forget to call free(current_record) before setting it back to NULL.

You should use ",\n" as the separator list for your calls to strtok
